# Vaildation Jquery plugin choices

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using [jquery validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to check the form before posting. However, since it has not updated for a long time, I am wondering whether it is still the best plugin to use.

Also, how can i check whether the select box have a option imputed or just default value which i need to warn my user?

Thank you.

Comment: Hiya, http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation since this is supported by Jquery official site it should be good. not sure about the **best** definition; for me thing that fits/extend into my project nicely is the best :) , hope this helps, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dude first u have to attach that js files in your js folder or wherever from you want to get that..

then you have to write code for jQuery in script ::---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery('#submit').click(function() {

       if(jQuery('#Idname option:selected').val() != ''){
                //your code here
               alert("you selected an option");
return true;
            }else{
alert("please select an option");
return false;
}


});

    });
</script>
```

check do something like that it will work.....

Comment: thanks Is it using a plugin or write the vaildation by yourself?

Comment: here you can write your custom function as well as jQuery validation by plugin also(inbulit function)...